# Difference between dot notation and string based IP

Tags: network-programming

When setting the IP for where the client should connect,do I need to make distinguish between and IP like 208.56.123.1 and one like "www.domain.com" ?

Comment: The client must use DNS to resolve www.domain.com into a IP.

Comment: that means using gethostbyname ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP is only the number.

So, 208.56.123.1 is IP, but www.domain.com is not - it's a symbolic name. Both are addresses, but only the number is IP.

Symbolic name will usually resolve to an actual IP using DNS server.

As to your question, will both work the same, the answer is - it only depends on how your client is implemented.

Both addresses should refer to the same location, though it might be better to target the symbolic name, because IP is more likely to change.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the use case. Most programming languages / network libraries come with built-in support for name resolution.
Low-level system calls like `bind()` or `connect()` do not support name resolution and require you to get the IP.